# Can I use usb tv tuner without pc?

Tags: tv, tuner-card

So here is the story:

I just got basic cable tv installed, but i don't have an actual TV. All I have is my pc with gorgeous 30 inch DELL WFP 3007 HC monitor.

Installer have told me that if my display would have an RCA connector at the back of the display, I would just plug it in there and watch. 
Since this monitor has only one input connector which is dual link DVI, I cant really plug anything in there.

Now i am going to buy a TV tuner. I have to make a decision which one to buy: internal PCI card or external usb?

My display has two usb ports on its side, would it be possible to just plug a usb tuner in there and watch it without use of PC? Will this work? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that will definitely not work. If you want to bypass the PC altogether, you just need to adapt the signal path.
This [DVI to RCA Component adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812270321&nm_mc=OTC-Froogle&cm_mmc=OTC-Froogle-_-Adapters+and+gender+changers-_-BYTECC+INC-_-12270321) will do the trick.
If you need to go to Composite, you'll need [this](http://www.hdtvsupply.com/component-to-composite-adapter.html) too.
This setup still won't be ideal, because you won't have a tuner either, as there is not one built into your monitor.
I did however find [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005U5RT), though I'm not sure it will work, but this kind of device would be your best option. It is a tv tuner for use with monitors.

Answer (score 9):

No, it will not work.  How would you tune channels, for example?

Answer (score 4):

No, as others have mentioned this will not work.  The two USB ports that are on your monitor are actually connected to your PC (assuming you have the USB cable coming out of your monitor plugged in).  They have nothing to do with the actual monitor, rather they are just mounted there for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

To use a television signal you need a tuner. If your monitor doesn't have a tuner built in then you can not hook a television signal into it. Some monitors have tuners in them that are marketed as Television Monitors and have various inputs such as coaxial and HDMI in. No matter how much you twist your cord coming from the wall or set-top box to fit into your Monitor's inputs, it simply won't work.

Ideally you just want to buy a TV, but otherwise I would recommend an internal PCI-based tuner card (marketed as TV Tuner Cards). Unfortunately this requires some of your processor power to run (and the computer obviously to be on) but the plus side to this is you can record TV directly on your computer. Some graphics cards also have a built in TV Tuner as well. You could also buy a monitor that is also a television as I mentioned above, and use it as a second monitor. That is the setup I have, and it works great. I can use my computer on the primary screen and switch between TV and a second display (thanks to Ultramon for turning off the signal to the second display) whenever I need.